# Space between label and form element

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, haml

I am new to bootstrap and HTML and want to know how can I give same spacing between form label and the text field, throughout the form. I have attached code snippet as well as an output form.

[code for the form][1][ Form output][2]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve] - code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question _in text form_, not as an image _of_ code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: you can use `<br>` or `margin` for so space

Comment: Provide your code so that we can help.

Comment: i have attached code snippet

Comment: the 'form-control' class should be added to all input fields. Labels and input should be grouped into DIV's with the 'form-group' class on. Should help with your spacing problem and line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing good. You need to just group your elements. Here I am going to write HTML code.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
    <label class="">small</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-right">
    <label class="">long lebel text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to set your label box and text box separate and push the label to the extreme right.  [You can check here](https://codepen.io/anshulsharma989/pen/qLKyJd). Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a specific column indent for your label:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">                            
    <label class="col-md-2" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">


 </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">                            
        <label class="col-md-2" for="idForTextfield">A very long text for this label:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idForTextfield" placeholder="your text">
    </div>
```

also you can add some column indent for your text field so that it bounden with your limited space just add `col-md-2` in the class for `<input>` tag.
Sample here [Code sample](https://codepen.io/mahfuzmr/pen/pqKOyB).

Happy coding :)